# Somebody heard about this encryption?

Tags: java, password-encryption

I've decrypted a packet with Aes 128 bit, and this the result I got. Has someone saw this before?

[B@766a24

Thanks !

Comment: We've all heard about AES128, but we have no idea what your problem is? Is this not what you expected? Are you using the right key, mode, etc?

Comment: yep. but i have just seen a mug shot :) what have he done? what is his language?

Comment: @wolive that wouldn't be an "invalid pointer," just printing a value that's meaningless to humans.

Comment: @Matt yes, you're right, bad choice of words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just `System.out.println()`d a Java `byte[]`.

Try using [`Arrays#toString(byte[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29).

Comment: +1 for good answer to bad question